# Closed Gaussian surface/cube/geometry

Tags: electrostatics

Is there a real life example of a closed Gaussian surface/cube/any geometry? Also, how do we place a charge inside a closed gaussian surface?

I also have another doubt regarding the position of charge in a closed Gaussian cube and the flux through it.

> Consider a charge placed at the corner of a cube or at one of the face of a cube → Why does not that charge project an electric field out side the cube or through an adjacent face? Is it because the cube is closed?

[image]

Comment: What do you think a "Gaussian cube" is?

Answer (score 1):

A Gaussian surface is a geometrical region, not a real surface.

> Consider a charge placed at the corner of a cube or at one of the face of a cube → Why does not that charge project an electric field out side the cube or through an adjacent face? Is it because the cube is closed?

I am not sure what you are asking. A charge placed anywhere on the cube will generally have field lines going through all faces. If the cube is a perfect conductor, the **net** electric field inside the cube will be zero, but the electric field lines *due to the charge* will still pass through various faces of said cube.

Comment: What if it is a closed Gaussian cube?